# "Segmentation fault (core dumped)" after explicit glibc linking.

Tags: c, gcc, linker, glibc

For some reason I have to link glibc manually. I am trying to run the following program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int _start(){
    printf("ABCDE");
    return 0;
}
```

In order to compile it I type the following commands:

```
gcc -c main.c -o main.o
gcc -L/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ -nostdlib main.o -o main -lc
```

Unfortunately, after running `./main` i get only
    Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Could anyone tell mi what i am doing wrong?

Comment: Are you trying to override the rt-startup ? because your id is [reserved](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier).

Comment: You have to link `-lc` manually because `-nostdlib` disables it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

an `_exit(0);` should do the trick.

However, what are you trying to achieve?
[Sample](http://learningpearls.blogspot.in/2011/02/start-function-inside-c.html)

Comment: Thank you very much! I have to write an application that will be running on an old kernel with old glibc version. I had find out if the linking will work correctly.

Comment: @nkdm The approach you've tried here is *exceedingly* unlikely to work on an older kernel once your program becomes slightly more complicated. You should probably read these answers: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2079757/50617 http://stackoverflow.com/a/8658468/50617

Comment: I had compiler that was dynamically linking GLIBC 2.15, but on target system i had GLIBC 2.4 that was incompatible. I thought that linking with '--static' option would take to much memory, but fortunately it was acceptable.